# Shipping - price vs destination with more results

Tags: shipping, table-rates

This is my tablerates.csv, for backend;:

```
"ITA","*","*",0,7
"ITA","*","*",18,4
"ITA","*","*",75,0
```

For example, if cart's amount is 66,94 euro, shipping cost is 4.

Anyway, It not works fine. I see that this is the query of Carrier/Tablerate model:

```
SELECT `shipping_tablerate`.* FROM `shipping_tablerate` WHERE (website_id=1) AND ((dest_country_id = "IT" AND dest_region_id = 260 AND dest_zip = 00018) OR (dest_country_id = "IT" AND dest_region_id = 260 AND dest_zip = '') OR (dest_country_id = "IT" AND dest_region_id = 0 AND dest_zip = '') OR (dest_country_id = "IT" AND dest_region_id = 0 AND dest_zip = 00018) OR (dest_country_id = '0' AND dest_region_id = 0 AND dest_zip = '')) AND (condition_name = "package_value") AND (condition_value <= 66.94) ORDER BY `dest_country_id` DESC, `dest_region_id` DESC, `dest_zip` DESC LIMIT 1
```

So, it returns only first record, but this isn't the right record: the query not order by **condition_value DESC**. 
So, it returns only a first,  randomic, row.
Why the Magento's developer set the query so? My csv/my purpose (3 range for every country/province) is wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It does order by condition_value desc, looks like your query is different so implies code was altered.

I checked 1.8.1 and 1.9.0.1 CE and this is whats there:

```
    $select = $adapter->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable())
        ->where('website_id = :website_id')
        ->order(array('dest_country_id DESC', 'dest_region_id DESC', 'dest_zip DESC', 'condition_value DESC'))
        ->limit(1);
```

I'm not aware of issues here.  If you need a more powerful tablerate solution look at MatrixRates which is very popular free shipping extn and allows more flexibility (and multiple shipping methods). That definitely works.